# Having trouble removing element from state array React/Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, state

Hello I am having some trouble with removing items from selectedTags state array onClick. Please see the below react component:

TagPosts.tsx

```js
interface Tag {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

const TagPosts: React.FC= () => {

  let [tags, setTags] = useState<Tag[]>([]);

  let [selectedTags, setSelectedTags] = useState<Tag[]>([]);


  // STATE IS BEING UPDATED FINE WITH THE BELOW addToSelected FUNCTION

  const addToSelected = (tag: Tag) => {
    setSelectedTags([...selectedTags, tag]);
  };

  // HAVING ISSUE WITH REMOVING ITEMS FROM SELECTED ARRAY. STATE IS NOT BEING UPDATED WITH THE BELOW FUNCTION

  const removeFromSelected = (tag: Tag) => {
    const index = selectedTags.indexOf(tag);
    const newSelectedTags = selectedTags;
    newSelectedTags.splice(index, 1);
    setSelectedTags(newSelectedTags);
  };

  const renderTags = tags.map((tag) => {
    if (!selectedTags.includes(tag)) {
      return (
        <StyledTagBox key={tag.id} onClick={() => addToSelected(tag)}>
          <Typography variant="displayTags">{tag.name}</Typography>
        </StyledTagBox>
      );
    } else if (selectedTags.includes(tag)) {
      return (
        <SelectedTagBox key={tag.id} onClick={() => removeFromSelected(tag)}>
          <Typography variant="displayTags" color="#fff">
            {tag.name}
          </Typography>
        </SelectedTagBox>
      );
    }
  });


export default TagPosts;
```

Can anyone spot the bug? The weird thing is that when i console.log the newSelectedTags variable it is showing the desired array but the setSelectedTags function in the line right after is not executing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Shallow copy your state: `const newSelectedTags = [...selectedTags];`

Answer (score 2):

React's state is immutable, and only checks reference equality.

The problem with your code is `splice` does not change the state reference.

You can use `filter` which is very common in React's array update. It will do 2 things:

- Remove items according to your condition
- Create a new array that makes React understand state update

```
  const removeFromSelected = (tag: Tag) => {
    const newSelectedTags = selectedTags.filter(currentTag => currentTag !== tag);
    setSelectedTags(newSelectedTags);
  };
```

Comment: This is the best way: it uses `filter` to both remove the item AND return a new array.

Answer (score 1):

Ah I had this problem plenty of times. The issue is with the rendering of the state.

Since you are copying `selectedTags` directly using `const newSelectedTags = selectedTags;`, the state hook thinks that nothing has changed. It is a very annoying feature but should be solved if you instead do something like:

`newSelectedTags = [...selectedTags]`

(A shallow copy as caTS suggested)